# How to Set an Alert Upon Generation of a new label?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

Hi Im trying to set an alert for my indicator the code is something that looks like this.

```
if barstate.islast

for x 
if y
label.new(signal)
```

This Code Generates several signals in my chart . and i want to set an alert upon generation of a new one ( new label being added to the chart )

Answer (score 0):

alerts can be placed in the local scope of your if statement as follows

```
if y
    label.new(signal)
    alert("A new label has been made")
```

Cheers and best of luck with your coding